# Spark/Scala: How do I get rows that is in Top X %?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe:

```
val df = Seq(
("q1", "a1", 0.31, "food"), ("q1", "a2", 0.01, "food"), ("q1", "a3", 0.51, "food"),
("q2", "b1", 0.01, "tools"), ("q2", "b2", 0.03, "tools"), ("q2", "b3", 0.01, "tools")
).toDF("id","part", "ratio", "category")
df.show(false)

+---+----+-----+--------+
|id |part|ratio|category|
+---+----+-----+--------+
|q1 |a1  |0.31 |food    |
|q2 |a2  |0.01 |food    |
|q3 |a3  |0.51 |food    |
|q4 |b1  |0.01 |tools   |
|q5 |b2  |0.03 |tools   |
|q6 |b3  |0.01 |tools   |
+---+----+-----+--------+
```

I am trying to find the threshold for each category based no the outlier in that category. For ex: in foods, 66% is more than 0.30 whereas in tools, almost all are >0.0. How do I find the thresholds such that majority of the ids are in the bigger bucket.

Any advice is helpful.

Tried:

```
spark.sql("select category, percentile_approx(ratio, 0.2) as threshold from df group by category order by category").show(1000, false)

+--------+---------+
|category|threshold|
+--------+---------+
|food    |0.31     |
|tools   |0.01     |
+--------+---------+
```

But the issue here is, I need to specify the X to get the threshold but I am looking for like a outlier detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining the range of the acceptable data in terms of mean and standard deviation and then finding out the rows that are outside the acceptable range

```
//define the acceptable range limits by looking at the mean and standard deviation    
val statsDF = df
          .groupBy("category")
          .agg(mean("ratio").as("mean"), stddev("ratio").as("stddev"))
          .withColumn("UpperLimit", col("mean") + col("stddev")*3)
          .withColumn("LowerLimit", col("mean") - col("stddev")*3).drop("mean","stddev")

// join statsDF with the original df and filter rows that are outside the acceptable range

val outliersDF= df.join(statsDF, usingColumns = Seq("category")).filter($"ratio"< $"LowerLimit" || $"ratio"> $"UpperLimit")
```

I have referenced [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/outlier-detection-an-etl-tutorial-with-spark-f4197eb84a7b) for this solution.